# Editing data not working on iOS with WatermelonDB realsed version

Tags: reactjs, react-native, watermelondb

Description:
I am encountering an issue with WatermelonDB where I am unable to edit data on iOS using the released version of React Native.

Expected behavior:
The record should be updated with the new data.

Actual behavior:
The record is not updated.

Error that is loggs on logger while we try to update update a data

*TypeError: Cannot assign to read-only property 'updated_at'*

*TypeError: Cannot assign to read-only property '_status'*

Additional information:

I have tried running the app in debuging mode on a physical iOS device as well as in the iOS simulator, and it works as expected in both environments.
I am using the latest version of WatermelonDB (version 0.25.5) and React Native (version 0.70.7).
I have not encountered this issue on Android.
Any help resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated!